# Does C# method take memory?

Tags: c#, performance, memory, memory-management, heap-memory

What happens in memory when there is a class with 50 methods and we create 50 object instances of that class? What is the best solution for having an `object` with a lot of functionality and less memory usage?

Comment: AFAIK, instances of a class takes memory only for their fields (auto-implemented properties included, since they are translated to regular properties with backing fields).

Comment: @ZoharPeled You are correct. Methods get their context provided, i.e. the instance they are working on, by the implicit `this` parameter or in the case of static methods don’t need a context. That’s why there is no need to copy methods in memory for different instances. Properties are just getter and setter methods, so the same applies. Which leaves fields as the stuff in an instance taking up memory.

Comment: Side note: class with 50 methods is often considered bad smell. You may want to review your design and see if all methods indeed must be in same object and no other grouping of method would provide ease of understanding/ use of you API.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, C#/.Net methods require memory on per-AppDomain basis, there is no per-instance cost of the methods/properties.

Cost comes from:

- methods metadata (part of type) and IL. I'm not sure how long IL stays loaded as it really only needed to JIT so my guess it is loaded as needed and discarded.
- after method is JITed machine code stays till AppDomain is unloaded (or if compiled as neutral till process terminates)

So instantiating 1 or 50 objects with 50 methods will not require different amount of memory for methods.

Comment: When memory is allocated for methods? Is it allocated at the time of object creation or at the of calling the method?

Comment: @zulqadaridrishi no idea (should be at JIT time)/unlikely anyone cares. Please ask a new question (make sure to explain why you need that info in your question)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly the memory usage and functionality is not based on the object, its based on the class of which we are making an object... hence if you are making a object of a class you are able to access all the functionality of that class.. and according to me its a better option to use a object for accessing a class functionality